# mongodb how to query records that have at least N key in giving keys?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, key

How to find records the have at least `N` same keys with the specific record?

For example the specific record has `k1`, `k2`, `k3`, `k4`, `k5` five keys. How to find records that has at least `3` keys than in the five keys?

For example current data is below and find docs that has at least 3 keys in `k1`,`k2`,`k3`,`k4`

```
doc1 {k2:1, k3:1, k4:1, k5:1, k6:1}
doc2 {k1:1, k3:1, k4:1, k5:1, k7:1}
doc3 {k1:1, k2:1, k4:1, k5:1, k8:1}
doc4 {k1:1, k2:1, k3:1, k5:1}
doc5 {k1:1, k2:1}
```

expected output:

```
doc1 {k2:1, k3:1, k4:1}
doc2 {k1:1, k3:1, k4:1}
doc3 {k1:1, k2:1, k4:1}
doc4 {k1:1, k2:1, k3:1}
```

Comment: Would be great if you can provide sample data and expected output

Comment: @ray I've added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the followings in an aggregation pipeline:

1. use `$objectToArray` to convert the `$$ROOT` document into an array of k-v tuples
2. use `$reduce` to count for array entries that the field are in `[k1,k2,k3,k4]`
3. keep only the count >= 3(or any other threshold you specified)
4. `$project` to your desired form

Here is a [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8ErqWHYh5q9) for your reference.